# Best way to periodically mirroring data from SQL to NoSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, postgresql, nosql

I want to export updated data from MySQL/postgreSQL to mongodb every time specified table has changed or, if that's impossible, make the dump of whole table to NoSQL every X seconds/minutes. What can I do to achieve this? I've googled and I found only paid, enterprise level solutions and those are out of reach for my amateur project.

Comment: You can use database triggers (ON Insert, Update and Delete) to fill a second (audit) table with the changes. You can scan this table, perform the corresponding updates in mongodb and mark them as done or delete them from that second audit table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/) provides and open source database replication option that would that has support for replicating a RDMS database (MySQL, Postgres) into MongoDB.

Here is the specific documentation to setup the Mongo target node in SymmetricDS.

http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.11/html/user-guide.html#_mongodb

There is also a blog about setting up Mongo in a bit more detail.

https://www.jumpmind.com/blog/mongodb-synchronization

Answer (score 1):

To get online replication into a target database you can use:

- Get the data stream at the same time in both databases
- Enterprise solution which reads the transaction log and pushes the data to the next database
- Check periodically for change dates > X
- Export table periodically
- Write changed records to a certain table with trigger and poll this table to select the changes
- Push the changed data with triggers in a datastreamservice into the next database
- Many additional approaches

Depending on the amount of time you want to use and the lag the data can have it depends which solution fits for your demand.

If the amount of data gets bigger or the number or transaction increases some solutions which fit for an amateur project don't fit anymore.